# Error: argument of type "cons char *" is incompatible with parameters of type "LPCWSTR"

Tags: c++

I am writing a code in Visual C++ to access serial port of a computer.

Code is given below:-

```
#include<windows.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cstring>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
//#include "stdafx.h"
#ifndef __CAPSTONE_CROSS_SERIAL_PORT__ 
#define __CAPSTONE_CROSS_SERIAL_PORT__
HANDLE hSerial= CreateFile("COM1", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,0,0,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,0);
```

In the above code I am getting an error at ""COM1"" in last line of above code.

Error is given below:-

```
Error: argument of type "cons char *" is incompatible with parameters of type "LPCWSTR"
```

I want to know why I am getting this error and who to resolve it.

Comment: This is a pure C++ question, no connection with electrical engineering. (On a more appropriate forum the first question put to you would probably be "what is the type of LPCWSTR?")

Comment: Except that they would know the answer ;-) Pointer to const null-terminated string of wide (UTF-16) chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CreateFileA to use the ANSI (ASCII string) version of the API call instead of the Unicode one or alternatively and probably the more portable way is to use the following macro to change the string type, this will work regardless of if you have a project targetting Unicode or not:

```
HANDLE hSerial= CreateFile(_T("COM1"), GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,0,0,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,0);
```

The following Unicode programming summary from Microsoft is quite brief and worth a read:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dybsewaf.aspx